# Trigger Azure Log analytics alert based on log file append

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

I need to try and create an alert for when a new entry is added to an application log file. Each new entry is time stamped. I have setup/imported the custom log as timestamped and tested with a dummy app log file and manually added entries. I initially set up the alert to trigger when the number of results is greater than 0. This appears to work but depending on the time intervals I set it will keep emailing me the alerts. Is there anyway I can get it to just alert the once for each time a new entry is added?

**Alert logic
Based on  - Number of results
Operator Greater than
Threshold value 0**

**Evaluation based on
Period(in Minutes)
1440**

**Frequency(in minutes)
240**

I have set these to cut down on the alert emails. Ideally i'd like it to check every hour and alert when new entry is added but only alert the once. Not sure if it can be done. Is there any tweaks to the Kusto query where I can get it to alert based on a row number increase. With setting the alert to greater than 0 I've a feeling it will always alert because all new entries will mean its higher than that value.

My basic Kusto query just returns lines that list a document number

**LogAppend_CL
| where RawData contains "for Document number"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your query properly. Do you want to get all the new records inserted every hour ?

Doesn't this alert condition work for you ? You configure an alert, which gets fired every 60 minutes and it goes back to the last 60 minutes and checks if there are any records matching you query and returns them in email.

Alert logic Based on - Number of results Operator Greater than Threshold value 0

Evaluation based on Period(in Minutes) -> 60

Frequency(in minutes) -> 60

Regards

Arun

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, I was on holiday. Yes it does work. I was getting myself confused. Works like a charm.